# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/codec/binary/Base64

Tags: java, tomcat, jar

When I click a particular radio button it should fetch a servlet but it is not able to find the above class. Where should I include the class path of the jar file? Also what are the jar files that has to be present
tomcat-util.jar
catalina-ant.jar
commons-codec-1.6.jar
opencsv-2.1-1.0.0.jar
xerces_2_6_2.jar

Should I include them in the manifest.mf in META-INF?
Please help me as I am struck with this for a long time now.

Comment: Unfortunately, NoClassDefFoundError is a "garbage" exception that can occur for about a dozen different reasons.  Most revolve around getting your jar files mucked up (the wrong version combos put together), but there are other causes.

Comment: If you use tomcat you should copy the fine in the lib folder of the tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you All for the suggestions. I just figured out that my .classpath in the project did not have the jar files location .

```
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/catalina-ant.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-util.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/opencsv-2.1-1.0.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/xerces-2_6_2.jar"/>
```

i added the above and it solved my problem. Thank you so much All.:)

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is, indeed, a "garbage exception" that usually gets thrown when your code was compiled with one version of the class and at runtime a different incompatible version is found by the class loader.  "Usually" is the operative term there.  Failure of static initializers is also a common source of this issue.

You can probably get around this by getting whatever JAR you used to compile your stuff into the WEB-INF/lib directory of your webapp.  If you are using Gradle or Maven I believe they will do this directly if you declare the dependency to be a compile dependency.